# Using ngCordova with Angular 2

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ngcordova

Can we use ngCordova while developing an app with Angular2?

ngCordova is developed with AngularJS as i know, is it competible with Angular2 also??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ionic-native [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native ]

Completely typescript support.

Example as per documentation:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Camera
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```